# Process of validating a user of a PhoneGap app against a webpage

Tags: android, session, cordova

I have a web-based app (PHP-MySQL-JavaScript) and now I'm in the task of creating an Android app using PhoneGap to connect to the web app and sinchronize data; to be used even off-line.

The issue is that I don't know how to validate and create a session in PhoneGap.

I know how to store data using "localStorage" but I don't know what is the best way to connect, send and retrieve data (JSON?) and manage sessions.

So, what is the state of the art to do this in a professional, efficient and secure way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery.
To retrieve data from a JSP web service:

```
function usejQueryGetJSONData(connUrl, listName) {
 jQuery.getJSON(connUrl, function(data){                
 listData = JSON.stringify(data);
 localStorage.setItem(listName, listData);  
});
}
```

Use PhoneGap to send data:

```
function uploadFiles(fileURI) {
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.fileKey="file";
options.fileName=fileURI.substr(fileURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
options.mimeType="text/plain";
options.chunkedMode = false;
var params = new Object();
options.params = params;
var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.upload(fileURI, "http://UrILink", win, failUpload, options);
}
```

I have log in function to do authentication but did not need to manage sessions.